# AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'related_stocks'

Tags: python, django

Django newbie here. I'm trying to create a simple app to discuss stocks, where users can create topics and establish many-to-many relationship to specific stocks. In the topic-detail page, I would like to show all the stocks related to that topic. I'm running into a roadblock: AttributeError 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'related_stocks'. Despite going through similar questions others have asked, I still can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please see my code below:

**models.py**

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    related_stocks = models.ManyToManyField(Stock)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,
                           db_index=True)
    def __str__(self):
    return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
            super(Topic, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('comments:topic_detail', args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

**views.py**

```
def topic_detail(request, id, slug):
    topic = Topic.objects.all().filter(id=id, slug=slug)
    related_stocks = topic.related_stocks
    return render(request,
                  'comments/comment/topic-detail.html',
                  {'section': 'topics',
                   'topic': topic,
                   'related_stocks': related_stocks})
```

**topic-detail.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}{{ topic.title }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Stocks associated with {{ topic.title }}.</h1>
    {% for related_stock in related_stocks %}
    <ul>
        <a href="{{ related_stock.get_absolute_url }}">
            {{ related_stock.ticker }}
        </a>
    </ul>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should user get instead of filter:

```
topic = Topic.objects.get(id=id, slug=slug)
```

filter returns array. get returns only one object and you need to handle object does not exist scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
topic = Topic.objects.all().filter(id=id, slug=slug)
related_stocks = topic.related_stocks
```

`filter` essentially returns a list of `Topic` models, so `topic` has no `related_stocks` attributes.

Either:

1. If you are sure `Topic.objects.all().filter(id=id, slug=slug)` will always return a single object, use `get` (keep in mind it will raise an exception if either an no object or more than 1 objects were found).
2. Change `Topic.objects.all().filter(id=id, slug=slug)` to `Topic.objects.all().filter(id=id, slug=slug)[0]` so you always pick the first `topic` object.

Comment: Thanks for the additional suggestions!